# Counting integer operations on Sandy Bridge

Tags: c, performance, papi

I'd like to calculate the computational intensity of my code, but it works with `integers`, not `floats`. I thought about counting the number of operations with PAPI, but the hardware doesn't provide counters for integer operations. How can I do this?

Comment: How about just counting all instructions?  E.g. callgrind can do this.

Comment: Unfortunately, that counts many more instructions that we need. We want to calculate actual arithmetic operations, while that will count other types of instructions as well.

Answer (score -1):

Valgrind's Lackey tool will give you ALU operation counts if you specify --detailed-counts=yes: 
http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/lk-manual.html

Comment: I think that operations such as pre-fetching (which I do NOT want to count) are also counted, no?

Comment: How can I know if it works, looking at the output?! The only thing I can do is try it on a very small code whose no. of operations I know.

Comment: Perfect, then do that!

Comment: It doesn't work...

SIZE = 500.000

 for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
 {
  x[i] = i * 2;
 }


data type of x: int; result: AluOps = 3,225,684

Comment: You know `x[i]` means `*(x + i)` right?  There are various hidden ALU operations, you will never get a simple "How many times did I add two numbers using the + operator?"

Comment: Right. However, and in short, I can't distinguish between "my" operations and "control" operations. That means that I can't estimate the computational intensity of the code, at least following this approach...